# Is it possible to start a Jupyter notebook on a boot?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, launchctl

I would like to open a Jupyter notebook page on the boot of my Mac. Specifically, I use the launchctl to start the Jupyter notebook.

However, after the reboot, the web page showed the password or token to verify:

[image]

Here is the launchctl script I use on High Sierra. I find it painstaking to bother to type in the token. So is it possible to ignore the token verification on reboot, just like it is when you type in `jupyter notebook`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
           http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>me.jupyter</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/bin/jupyter</string>
      <string>notebook</string>
      <string>--no-browser</string>
      <string>--port</string>
      <string>9090</string>
      <string>--notebook-dir</string>
      <string>/Users/me/jupyter/</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true />
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true />
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/jupyter/jupyter-notebook.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/mejupyter/jupyter-notebook.stdout</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Is the image shown in my post? Now my Wi-Fi is pretty slow but I could not find it yet...

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

> If you do not care about the security of the server, you can first create a jupyer config file with:
>   cd ~/.jupyter
>   jupyter notebook --generate-config
>   Then set the c.NotebookApp.token parameter to an empty string in the configuration file created
>   c.NotebookApp.token = ''
>   As said in comment, Setting to an empty string disables authentication altogether, which is NOT RECOMMENDED.

Source: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2254

Comment: I see. But as long as I run the server on localhost, it would not be that unsafe, right?

Comment: It's perfectly safe if you run it only locally. The reason password/token protection was made the default is presumably that a lot of people do not understand the difference between a public webserver and localhost.

Comment: I wouldnt call running a local instance of anything without any authentication safe, but, as they say, "Security is a state of mind".

Answer (score 1):

Actually in later versions of Jupyter notebook, you must explicitly run the server with the parameter `--NotebookApp.token=`. So add it to the plist file.

And as the other answer notes, writes the following on the config file:

```
c.NotebookApp.token = ''
```